# Why I get this type error with generics in annotations?

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I have this annotation:

```
public @interface ModelType {

    Class<? extends ValueFilter<?, ?>> value();

}
```

and this two classes:

```
public class UserIntermediateModel<T> implements ValueFilter<T, User> {
    // ...
}

public class UserModel extends UserIntermediateModel<User> {
    // ...
}
```

I can use the annotation with `value = UserModel.class`, but not with `value = UserIntermediateModel.class`:

```
incompatible types: Class<UserIntermediateModel> cannot be converted to Class<? extends ValueFilter<?,?>>
```

Why so?

Comment: `UserIntermediateModel.class` is a raw  type, i.e. the generic types needed for  `ValueFilter` are not known. On the other hand `User` already defines all the generic types at compile time.

Comment: Understood. But why I can use raw types with `Class<?>` then, and not with `Class<? extends Foo<?>>`?

Comment: As a workaround, you can use `Class<? extends ValueFilter>`.

Comment: Well, any class matches `Class<?>`, i.e. `UserIntermediateModel.class` is equivalent to `Class<UserIntermediateModel>`.